# How to use Google App Engine MapReduce with large amount of data ( >1000000 )

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

I implemented very simple mapreduce pipeline and stacked with some problems.

The scenario is, there are more than 1000000 entity in one kind of model in cloud datastore and I'd like to check all entity whether each entity has inconsistency property.

Here is my code snippet.

```
class User(ndb.model)
    parent = ndb.KeyProperty(Group) # want to check if this key property actually exist


class CheckKeyExistencePipeline(pipeline.Pipeline):

    def map(self, entity):
        logging.info(entity.urlsafe()) # added for debug
        prop = getattr(entity, 'parent')
        if not prop.get():
            yield 'parent does not exist: %s\n' % (entity.key.urlsafe())

    def run(self, modelname, shards):
        mapreduce_pipeline.MapperPipeline(
            'parent check',
            handler_spec='CheckKeyExistencePipeline.map',
            input_reader_spec='mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader',
            output_writer_spec="mapreduce.output_writers.GoogleCloudStorageOutputWriter",
            params={
                'input_reader': {
                    'entity_kind': 'User',
                },
                'output_writer': {
                    'bucket_name': app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name(),
                    'content_type': 'text/plain'
                }
            },
            shards=10)
```

The problem is, it shows error like bellow really frequently.

> Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 133 MB after
>   servicing 2 requests total

There is no problem when I run this code with data around 10000 entities. 
What is a problem and how can I correctly configure this pipeline to apply large amount of data?

**EDIT1**

I modified not to use ndb cache, but it seems no improvement. I guess cache is already off default according to the source code.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/blob/6e103ac52855c3214de3ec3721d6ec0e7edd5f77/python/src/mapreduce/util.py#L381-L383

```
def _set_ndb_cache_policy():
    """Tell NDB to never cache anything in memcache or in-process.
    This ensures that entities fetched from Datastore input_readers via NDB
    will not bloat up the request memory size and Datastore Puts will avoid
    doing calls to memcache. Without this you get soft memory limit exits,
    which hurts overall throughput.
    """
    ndb_ctx = ndb.get_context()
    ndb_ctx.set_cache_policy(lambda key: False)
    ndb_ctx.set_memcache_policy(lambda key: False)
```

I did further investigation to find out the problem. I set one of the mapper parameter `processing_rate` to 10 and `shards` to 100, so that it only process 1 or 2 entity for each task.

Here is the mapreduce stat. The graph seems reasonable. (The pipeline is not finished yet at this time.)

[image: mapreduce detail]

But when I check the trace log of one of the worker task, it is really weird. It shows bunch of `/datastore_v3.Next` and `/datastore_v3.Get` despite the fact that the 'map' function is called only twice (according to my debug log.) Since I did not change the batch_size, it should be 50. So, in my understanding,  `/datastore_v3.Next` should be called only once and `/datastore_v3.Get` twice.

[image: tracelog]

Does anyone know why such many RPC calls to database are triggered?

**EDIT2**

Again, I did further investigation and made the code simple. The map function just get data using `ndb.Key` by calling it's `get` function.

```
class CheckKeyExistencePipeline(pipeline.Pipeline):

    def map(self, entity):
        logging.info('start')
        entity.parent.get()
        logging.info('end')


    def run(self):
        mapreduce_pipeline.MapperPipeline(
            'parent check',
            handler_spec='CheckKeyExistencePipeline.map',
            input_reader_spec='mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader',
            output_writer_spec="mapreduce.output_writers.GoogleCloudStorageOutputWriter",
            params={
                'input_reader': {
                    'entity_kind': 'User',
                },
                'output_writer': {
                    'bucket_name': app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name(),
                    'content_type': 'text/plain'
                }
            },
            shards=10)
```

The Tracelog of Stackdriver is like this.

[image: trace log]

It's just calling `get` but it triggers RPC call many times between 'start' and 'end'. It seems a little bit weird and could be one of the reason of this memory consumption. Is this regular behavior?

Comment: Sometimes you can fill up a lot of memory using the per instance cache that `ndb` provides.  You can fetch the entities without using the cache:  `prop.get(use_cache=False)`.  In this case, since you aren't doing a bunch of gets on the same key in a row, you don't gain anything from the cache anyway ... You can also try to [increase the instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/about-the-standard-environment#instance_classes) for the service handling these requests...

Comment: yes, the caching will end up being the key component here (and in general caching ndb entities is not helpful unless you *know* you'll reuse them). You might want to make the iterator be key-based instead so you can better control cache behavior.

Comment: Ohh I got it. I did not think about cache. I will try. Thanks!

Comment: Jeff, what does it mean by 'key-based'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally found what the problem is.

The point is that MapReduce uses `ndb.query.iter` and it uses `eventloops` to manage async RPC calls. In my MapReduce call, it triggers two types of RPC call, one is triggered by MapReduce library to fetch database records (A), and the other is by my `map` function (B).

If I do not trigger any RPC call inside my `map` function, there is no place to trigger next RPC call. Which means the next (A) is only triggered after batched 50 records are iterated. However, the attempt for (B) triggers next RPC call, and since the RPC calls are not triggered serially (which means it is not FIFO queue), it could be very possible that (A) to be triggered continuously until it fetches all entities.

I set `shards` to 100 but still one shard is responsible for totally 10000 records. Thus, that exceeds the soft memory limit.

And when I increase `shards` to 10000, another error happens...

In conclusion, There is no way to use MapReduce with large data with low memory instance. I guess.

For detail, please check the issues bellow.

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11648
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9610 (original issue)